# Unity 2D:RayCast2D not returning values as expected

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm having an issue with the RayCast2D. After reading the documentation it should be working, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code below is designed to stop the NPC from shooting if there is a wall between it and its target, however its still ignoring the walls completely and just shooting at them. My best guess is that its a logic issue of some kind but I can't figure out whats wrong.

```
  //Check has line of sight on target
                     RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, sleepDistance); //Uses raycast to see whats in front of player
                     if (hit)
                     {
                         if (!hit.collider.transform.CompareTag("Obstacle"))//Checks if wall is not in front of player
                             transform.GetChild(0).SendMessage("fireGun", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver); //Fires gun if wall is not in front of player
                         else
                             Debug.Log("Cast: " + hit.transform.tag); //Debug to see when wall is in front of player, never triggered.
                     }
```

I've double checked to make sure the walls are all properly tagged, and that its spelled right and everything.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to debug.log in the 'if' branch too, to see what did the raycast hit? Not impossible the source GameObject is inside something (e.g. character) and it bumps into it, instead of the wall (which has a collider, right?). You could also try Debug.DrawRay to see if your raycasting really is correct (use one color for walls, another color for triggering a shot). Let us know the results. One last thing: instead of "if (hit)" you should test "if (hit.collider != null)"

Comment: Will give this a try and get back to you. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Mark is right except I can't think of a case where hit.collider would be null

Comment: @NikaKasradze It is very easily possible. Either you cast to neverland (outside game area), or to the wrong coord/direction in 2D (e.g. "toward camera" or just "upwards"), or your objects have no collider so ray passes through them, or your raycast distance is too short, or layer is ignored, or obj. has no "thickness" in 2D and you set min/maxDepth.... hm... I think that's all. So this happens more often than not, especially if something is buggy